# has no attribute error while using scvi python package

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working with `conda enviroment` and tried to install `scvi`, which is a `python package` for data analysis, using the following commands (separately not together):

```
conda install scvi-tools -c conda-forge
conda install -c bioconda scvi
```

I could import it in python using:

```
import scvi
```

but, when I tried the following command:

```
>>> scvi.model.SCVI.setup_anndata(adata)
```

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'scvi' has no attribute 'model'
```

Do you know how to fix the issue?

Comment: Did you try the examples in the documentation? Do they work? Where the code says `scvi.model.SCVI.setup_anndata(adata)`, what do you think this should mean, and why? In particular, what should the `scvi.model` part mean? Why should `scvi` have an attribute called `model`?

Answer (score 1):

Install only `scvi-tools` you no longer need `scvi`.

Once you install it successfully then see this answer on git hub:

"*Hmm.. I see that the scvi-tools version I got is 0.8.1 while conda seems to have 0.20.1. Perhaps that's why. And for me, conda refuses to update this package. Possibly conflicting with some other package*.

*Update: Ok. cellxgene was messing up the conda env. Removed that, updated fsspec, pytorch-lightning and finally scvi-tools to 0.20.1 which solved this issue.*"

A link to git hub issue: https://github.com/scverse/scvi-tools/issues/824